# HP sound bug - very puzzling

Tags: audio

I recently got a HP Envy 4 Ultrabook 1002TX and have a very annoying issue with the sound.

Symptoms:

1. The laptop detects the headphones as plugged in when they are not. (Because of this I get no sound)
2. When I do plug in headphones, it detects the headphones as being plugged out, and I get sound from the inbuilt speaker. (Doesn't matter if they are headphones or external speakers).
3. When I plug in both a headphones set and a microphone, the laptop detects both of these as properly plugged in and outputs to the headphones and get input from the microphones.

I am not sure if this problem existed when I bought the PC, since I forgot to test the sound then, but it was definitely there from the first time I played some music.

Also, I dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 and the same problem, ( all 3 parts from above) exists in both OS'es.

What could be the issue?

PS: I am guessing hardware or BIOS. The BIOS says it is the latest, i.e. F.OA, according to the HP site. Is this actually the latest BIOS release for my PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a faulty soldering connection on or near the sound ports, take it back to where you purchased it if its still within warranty

Comment: Yup, faulty headphone jack would be my guess as well. Take it back.

Comment: hmm.. they are sending someone to replace the speakers and the system board. Just wanted to check if anyone else had the same problem or could suggest some other reason, other than hardware.